# Using iOS 8 flexible table cells, cell height changes but text doesn't wrap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

I'm trying to use the new method of creating flexible height cells in iOS 8 by instantiating with these two lines of code:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomatic Dimension
```

I've set autolayout constraints that all satisfied. When I put in the message "This is a test message." the table cell adjusts for the correct height for that short message.

However when I try to add text that causes the text to wrap (in this case I just copied and pasted "This is a test message." 9 times over), the cell height adjusts for the new content but the text doesn't wrap. I've set the number of lines on the label to 0. Thoughts?

Comment: What constraints so you have on the label with the long text?

Comment: Just 4 constraints on each side constraining them to the nearest view. Top is attached to a label which is attached to top margin, left is left margin, right is right margin, bottom is bottom margin.

Comment: Is the label expanding its height (give it a background color to see), but just not wrapping the text?

Comment: It looks like the table cell height is changing but the UILabel is staying the same single-line height

Comment: It shouldn't do that if you have it connected from the top of the cell to the bottom (through other views as necessary). Are you getting any warnings in the console?

Comment: No warnings in the console. I've been trying to mess with "content hugging priority" and "content compression resistance priority" as well to no avail.

Comment: Sometimes you do need to change one of those values so the system knows which view to expand or contract. Is the system giving you suggestions in IB for changing these?

Comment: Super weird but I just created an entirely new cell and re-added all of the constraints. Now it's working. I also tweaked the UILabel to have a higher compression resistance priority. Thanks for help troubleshooting man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new table cell and tweaked one of my labels compression resistance priorities to be 751 instead of 750.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue but only on the 5/5s, while the 6/6+ worked.

The solution I found was to make the cell in the nib wider than 320 points, and force it to re-calculate its preferredMaxLayoutWidth:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.questionLabel.frame.size.width;

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

When iOS has to resize the cell to fit in the Table View it will recalculate the wrapping of the cell's content.