# UITableViewCell calculates the correct height, but the UILabel doesn't wrap

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, uilabel

I can't get the UILabel to automatically word wrap without setting an explicit preferred width. Please help.

Here's my Interface Builder for UILabel in a UITableViewCell

[image: UILabel IB Attributes Inspector]
[image: UILabel IB Size Inspector]

And my result is:

[image: Application Example Result]

However, if I specify an explicit preferredWidth as in:

[image: explicit height]

I get the following:

[image: With wordwrapping]

Granted it has some weird vertical spacing, but at least it's wrapping correctly.

Also, here's how I'm building the row in my UITableViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? BurnFeedTableViewCell ??
        BurnFeedTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: Constants.CellReuseIdentifier)

    cell.nameOfBurnLabel?.text = object.objectForKey("name") as? String
    if let owner = object.objectForKey("owner") as? PFUser {
        cell.ownerLabel?.text = owner.username
    } else {
        cell.ownerLabel?.text = "unknown"
    }

    return cell
}
```

and defining the rowHeight & estimatedRowHeigh as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I would really like to get this working without having to specify an explicit height. Also, I have played around with the contentCompressionResistancePriority with no luck.

This is definitely similar to the following SO Question: [Using iOS 8 flexible table cells, cell height changes but text doesn't wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197594/using-ios-8-flexible-table-cells-cell-height-changes-but-text-doesnt-wrap)

However, the solution there doesn't seem to be working. In fact, there are a few similar questions. I cannot seem to get them to work though.

**EDIT**: XML of the tableViewCell from main.storyboard

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="Burn Feed Cell"
               rowHeight="95" id="bif-hV-Vqt" customClass="BurnFeedTableViewCell" customModule="Burn"
               customModuleProvider="target">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="44"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES"
                              contentMode="center" tableViewCell="bif-hV-Vqt" id="KGP-Sx-cZC">
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <subviews>
            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251"
                   verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="owner" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation"
                   baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO"
                   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TZ9-cx-K29">
                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="37" width="48" height="21"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251"
                   verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Burn Name" lineBreakMode="wordWrap" numberOfLines="0"
                   baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" preferredMaxLayoutWidth="90"
                   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="v96-dx-9z5">
                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="584" height="21"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251"
                   verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="countdown" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation"
                   baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO"
                   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6YZ-ne-79f">
                <rect key="frame" x="506" y="37" width="86" height="21"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
        </subviews>
        <constraints>
            <constraint firstItem="v96-dx-9z5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KGP-Sx-cZC"
                        secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="Iwe-kT-1Do"/>
            <constraint firstItem="6YZ-ne-79f" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="KGP-Sx-cZC"
                        secondAttribute="trailingMargin" id="JOA-d6-q3X"/>
            <constraint firstItem="6YZ-ne-79f" firstAttribute="baseline" secondItem="TZ9-cx-K29"
                        secondAttribute="baseline" id="JXU-Hf-vVb"/>
            <constraint firstItem="TZ9-cx-K29" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KGP-Sx-cZC"
                        secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="VOG-Xh-9wd"/>
            <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="TZ9-cx-K29"
                        secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="am1-l0-8EV"/>
            <constraint firstItem="TZ9-cx-K29" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="v96-dx-9z5" secondAttribute="bottom"
                        constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="jLQ-yQ-A8V"/>
            <constraint firstItem="v96-dx-9z5" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="KGP-Sx-cZC"
                        secondAttribute="trailingMargin" id="sl2-Fb-sWy"/>
            <constraint firstItem="v96-dx-9z5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="KGP-Sx-cZC" secondAttribute="topMargin"
                        id="xt3-Em-EaP"/>
        </constraints>
    </tableViewCellContentView>
    <connections>
        <outlet property="countdownLabel" destination="6YZ-ne-79f" id="te1-QF-Nuo"/>
        <outlet property="nameOfBurnLabel" destination="v96-dx-9z5" id="Wki-e1-0Np"/>
        <outlet property="ownerLabel" destination="TZ9-cx-K29" id="wqh-Cj-yQX"/>
    </connections>
</tableViewCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with autolayout. In order to get correct width/height wrapping you need to assure that for all elements in your `UITableViewCell` are properly constrained from the left margin of the cell to the right and from the top margin to the bottom.

Comment: I am aware of this and everything should be able to calculate it's x and you coordinates without ambiguity. I have played around with various dimensions with no luck. If I were to share my constraints would you be able to tell me what needs to be fixed?

Comment: sure. post all the constraints on cell elements with your question

Comment: Edited question with the subject tableview's xml from main.storyboard

Comment: any comment on the constraints I added to the question?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results. Try this: https://github.com/kellanburket/swift-tableview-test. I've been running it with the same constraints and the tableview cells stretch accordingly. Is there anything else you've introduced into your code that's not in the constraints somehow?

Comment: I created a github repo for this not sure what files in an xcode project or necessary so it might contain some unnecessary stuff.

https://github.com/jpgilchrist/parse-swift-test

The only thing that might be introduced is the use of parse UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled autoresizing mask translation for all labels?

```
cell.nameOfBurnLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
cell.ownerLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
cell.countdownLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

At least that is what I had to do to get dynamic cell heights to work with labels.

Comment: Not necessary since the Cell is part of a storyboard